# Performance of cancelPreviousPerformRequests

Tags: objective-c, performance, nsobject, delayed-execution

I use `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` to delay a layout operation so that it's not done multiple times.  Normally, I do something like this (example only):

```
- (void) setViewNeedsLayout{
    if (!_viewsNeedLayout){
        _viewsNeedLayout = YES;
        [self performSelector:@selector(layoutViews) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
    }
}

- (void) layoutViews{
    _viewsNeedLayout = NO;
    //layout views
}
```

It's pretty simple, efficient and effectively delays the layout operation until the end of the current run loop, but it does require that I keep track of the ivar: `_viewsNeedLayout`.

However, I'm wondering about the performance of `cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:selector:object:`. Instead of using an iVar to keep track of whether I've kicked off the delayed selector, I'm wondering if it might be better to do something like this:

```
- (void) setViewNeedsLayout{
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(layoutViews) object:nil];
    [self performSelector:@selector(layoutViews) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
}
```

Now, the issue is how performant is `cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget`?  In some cases, the respective `setViewNeedsLayout` method (or equivalent) could get called possibly hundreds of times... as an extreme example.  But it is an easier way to deal with the delayed/queued method call so I'd prefer to use it if it's not going to have a significant impact on performance.

Comment: It shouldn't affect performance. But it should also be easy for you to test.

Comment: No, it shouldn't be hard to test but if someone already has already done the testing then I figured it would be good to have it up on SO.  If not, then I'll do the testing and post it as the answer in a week or so.